# Notice: Undefined index: animation in

Tags: php, wordpress

I use wordpress.
I add animation to widget (successfully added)
But in my frontpage i get this notice

```
Notice: Undefined index: animation in /home/xx/layouts/widget.php on line 99
Notice: Undefined variable: animation in /home/xx/layouts/widget.php on line 101
```

Line 99 :

```
if ($params['animation']) $animation = 'data-uk-scrollspy="{cls:\''.$params['animation'].'\'}"';
```

Line 101 :

```
echo '<div class="'.implode(' ', $classes).'" '.$animation.'>'.$badge.$title.$content.'</div>';
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 99 :

```
$animation = "";
if (isset($params['animation'])) $animation = 'data-uk-scrollspy="{cls:\''.$params['animation'].'\'}"';
```

And maybe you could add a default animation

Comment: Thanks this solution worked perfectly.Now i want to use new code for line99-can you fix this code?-----code-----if ($params['animation']) $animation = 'data-uk-scrollspy="{cls:\''.$params['animation'].'\''.(($params['animation_repeat']) ?', repeat: true':'').'}"';

Answer (score 1):

in array $params You don't have element: 'animation'

to quick repair :

change 99 to:

```
 $animation = isset($params['animation']) ? 'data-uk-scrollspy="{cls:\''.$params['animation'].'\'}"' : '';
```

Comment: Thanks for answer . I change this line but now all of object have animation didn`t load

Comment: Animations are not loaded because $params don't have 'animation' element. Before changing animations work properly?

Comment: Yes animation work perfect.But i get this notic.After i change this line animation didn`t work

Comment: can You try new answer ?

Comment: sorry for my bad english.
before your answer animation worked perfectly.After your solution now animation not work and object not load (didn`t show)

Comment: my english is to no good :D. But did you tried my corrected answer ? In the old missed one character. You can also try: $animation = isset($params['animation']) ? 'data-uk-scrollspy="{cls:\''.$params['animation'].'\'}"' : 'data-uk-scrollspy="{cls:\'\'}"';

Comment: thanks this last code worked fully.but i have new code for line 99 this code get same notic on frontpage------------if ($params['animation']) $animation = 'data-uk-scrollspy="{cls:\''.$params['animation'].'\''.(($params['animation_repeat']) ?', repeat: true':'').'}"';